# Registering resource for ActiveAdmin inside Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

it would be great if it is possible to:

- create an Engine
- create Models inside this Engine (with migrations and seeds)
- create ActiveAdmin resources for every Model inside this Engine

and later... use it in every new app as easy as including new gem 'activeadmin_addons'

for example, i have to manually clone every time AdminUser resource, often, Catalog, User, Article and some others

thanx in advance

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Why would you want to couple your engine which has all the models with ActiveAdmin? Wouldn't it be better to separate your decouple your administration with all your core models?

Comment: I am not sure I remember why i asked what i asked =) but in general the main idea can be figured out with answer i accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the active admin wiki entry:

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Define-a-resource-inside-an-engine